# Use it headless and click buttons/links

Tags: dotnetbrowser

I want to use dotnetbrowser headless. Load a page extract data, fill in test boxes and click a button. Get the next page and so on.

Possible or not?
If possible, exampes?

With best regards

Gerhard

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.
Please take a look at the following articles:

- [Loading the WEB page.](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110055-loading-url-synchronously)
- [Setting Input Field Value & Working With Form](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110038-setting-input-field-value-working-with-form)
- [Simulating Click on DOM Element](https://dotnetbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000110033-simulating-click-on-dom-element)

Comment: Hi,thanks a lot. My target pages containing some JavaScript, can this Scrips running as in a Standard browser?